# Is a question about UML definitions something to be asked on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I'm trying with this question to draw a line between which question is specific of the technical side, programming and which I'm not sure if it qualifies, and if not, where to place it?

Particularly is about correct usage of composition and aggregation when designing, given an example.

> Let's say I have a ElementCollection Class and an Element Class 
>   the relationship between them is an aggregation or composition?

It's not the same as "Car and Engine", or "Car and neon lights" because the Collection may exist without items, but it's pointless.

So, is Stack Overflow the correct Stack Exchange site to put it?

Comment: *but I think you get what I mean.* Uh, I may be dense, but no. Could you quote at least part of the question you want to post in your meta-question here?

Comment: I edited it recently for a better understanding. Could someone explain me why is this voting for closure even existing?
I'm just trying to understand if system design goes in StackOverflow. There's no need to be mean.

Comment: I guess the close voter (and maybe the downvoter) acted before you edited your question (the close vote reason is "unclear what you're asking"). That said, if the sentence you added is the whole question you intend to post, I'm afraid it won't be well-received on any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Well, we have the [tag:uml-modeling] tag and other UML related. I'd say it's fine to ask UML related questions on SO. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388114/c11-variadic-template-parameters-notation-in-uml) for example.

Comment: Frederic, I'm almost sure it was afterwards, I saw the "asyncronous downvoting doing its magic" while I was expecting an answer to my edition.

Comment: @apacay To answer your off-meta question BTW: A `ElementCollection` class, certainly is a [_composition_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition). It's sole purpose is to contain the `Element` class instances.

Comment: Thanks πάντα. Even if it could exist *empty* by itself?

Comment: @apacay _"Even if it could exist empty by itself?"_ Yes. Have a look at that explanatory link. It may be instantiated, but kind of _useless_ if empty.

Comment: I'd suggest that you post it on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Some advise I read somewhere here on meta: use StackOverflow when you are working in your IDE, use programmers.stackexchange.com when you are in front of a white board. UML seems whiteboard to me.

Comment: To adress the UML question, and not the meta-question, wouldn't the relationship be that the Collection class "has a" Element class?

Comment: Why should you be policing other peoples questions in the first place???

Comment: So was the consensus that this isn't on topic at SO? I ask because I just saw one and there doesn't seem to be a lot of overwhelming support either way.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as the *correct* use of aggregation and composition. It's a matter of taste. Which is to say, a matter of opinion. Wrapping a design problem in UML doesn't change its nature. It's still an entirely subjective design question.

If you turn your question into a concrete example of UML, I suppose that Code Review might accept it. I'm not active there, so I can't tell definitively. I don't see how this can be an on-topic question on Stack Overflow.